# Como funciona o arredondamento do string format?

Tags: c#, .net, valor-monetário, arredondamento

Considere o seguinte trecho de código:

```
decimal myValue = 3.045M;

Console.WriteLine("Result by Math.Round = " + Math.Round(myValue, 2));
Console.WriteLine("Result by string.Format = " + string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:C}", myValue));
```

Os resultados são:

```
// Result by Math.Round = 3.04
// Result by string.Format = R$3,05
```

Eu sei o `Math.Round()` usa o padrão IEEE 754, seção 4, [conforme essa documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.math.round?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8), chamado também de padrão ***banker's rounding***.

Mas por que o `string.Format()` conforme a cultura especificada retorna um resultado diferente? Percebi que o resultado é o mesmo para diferentes culturas, como se o método de arredondamento fosse diferente do padrão do `Math.Round()`.

[Este documento do IBGE](https://biblioteca.ibge.gov.br/visualizacao/livros/liv82497.pdf) concorda com o padrão do IEEE.

Qual o motivo da diferença e qual método seria o mais apropriado para sistemas financeiros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resposta simples é que eles são diferentes, não há nenhum compromisso de serem iguais porque eles servem para propósitos diferentes, por isso sempre é bom usar o que realmente deseja. Não tem dicotomia entre eles.

Se quer fazer certo mande arredondar e apresente o resultado já arredondado. Sempre lembro que textos não são números ainda que as pessoas teimem em achar que são, se quer trabalhar com números trabalhe com eles e deixe a representação textual só para apresentar o número exato que já tem sem correr risco de inconsistências.

Números existem por si só no computador e são eles que podem ser manipulados com cálculos, o que vemos em uma tela ou outra forma de apresentação são textos que representam esses números. Então o dado que já tem é um número e faça tudo com ele até que precise apresentar, incluindo possíveis arredondamentos.

Alguma coisa me diz que você acha que não acontece um `String.Format()` no primeiro caso, mas todo `Writexxx()` e outros métodos que apresentam informações pegam objetos que não sejam textos e aplicam um `String.Format()` antes de apresentar, até porque estes métodos só sabem apresentar textos (*strings*), e não números). O mesmo vale para alguns [`ToString()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Decimal.cs,52c23e8c1bba6a83,references), que é usado neste caso, afinal não é possível concatenar um número com um texto, por isso há uma conversão implícita para texto quando chama a concatenação e isto é feito com a mesma função.

Eu consegui achar uma [resposta que dá alguma sustentação sobre isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227282/221800) já que é uma das pessoas que trabalhou no projeto e ele argumenta que é por questão de compatibilidade com um erro cometido há muito tempo atrás.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -2):

Na minha opinião você poderia utilizar `Console.WriteLine("Result is = " + Format(myValue, "#.##0,0#"));` Dessa forma você manteria ser valor original, sem realizar alterações e manteria o valor real.

Como sistema financeiro, creio que perder alguns décimos possa fazer diferença ao final dos cálculos.